# Apache Shiro Login not working as intended (Session get created before login)

Tags: shiro

I'm having trouble to get the login / logout features to work with my web application....
I'm using apache shiro 1.2 and my accpilcation is named SSP

here is my configuration:

**EDIT: Updated Code**

some code from web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

some code from shiro.ini: (Edit: changed url filter order)

```
[main]

shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp

# this is my own AuthenticationFilter which works fine
authc = com.mycompany.ssp.AuthFilter

authc.failureKeyAttribute=shiroLoginFailure

# redirect after successful login
authc.successUrl  = portal.jsp

######################################
# NOT ACTIVE CODE ####################
# login URL
#authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
# redirect after logout
#logout.redirectUrl = /login.jsp
######################################

[urls]
# enable logout filter
/logout = logout
# enable authc filter for all application pages
/** = authc
```

some code from portal.jsp

```
<a href="/SSP/logout"> Log out V2 </a></br>
```

I'm having 1 Problem and 1 issue that I dont understand:

**Problem**

- When I visit my webapplication via https://localhost:8443/SSP/
  I get a session id eventhough the user is not logged in yet:

  https://localhost:8443/SSP/login.jsp;JSESSIONID=6560e585-d871-4839-a606-464b4b314457
- Login works as intended, redirection to portal.jsp works

**Here I just want to be redirected to https://localhost:8443/SSP/login.jsp without a session being created !!**

**EDIT:**

My Session Management right now looks like this (shiro.ini

```
# SESSION MANAGEMENT #

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager

# Use the configured native session manager:
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

# 3,600,000 milliseconds = 1 hour
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 3600000

########################################################################
# CACHE MANAGEMENT #

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
```

**Issue** **->** **SOLVED thx to [Markus K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5851368/markus-k)**

- The logout via the Link "Log out V2" which uses the LogoutFilter (configured in shiro.ini) works fine but I dont understand how I get redirected back to /SSP/login.jsp although the line `logout.redirectUrl = /login.jsp` in shiro.ini is not active??
- My best guess here is that the line `shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp` tells shiro "hey after a logout go here again", but I'm not sure.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I am new to shiro too. But maybe I can help with some of your problems.

> be able to log out the user via the LogoutFilter configured in shiro.ini

In your shiro.ini you configured to use the `authc` filter to be used for all incoming requests `/**`:

```
/** = authc
/logout = logout
```

This means that a request to a url like `/logout` will be passed through the `authc` filter and not through the `logout` filter as intended. Changing the filter order should solve the problem.

```
/logout = logout
/** = authc
```

See http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-URLPathExpressions.
Regarding the logout servlet mapping in your web.xml. I'm not sure what you want to achieve there. I think you can just remove it and use the shiro logout filter as described above.

> Show user login.jsp when he visits the wep applicaton page
>
> login the user

Restricting all urls and providing a login.jsp should solve it. As I said, I am new to shiro too. So instead of giving possibly erroneous explanations I give you a configuration which works for me for the described requirenments.

```
[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp

[urls]
/login.jsp = authc
/logout = logout
/specific/url = authc, roles[ADMIN] 
/** = authc
```

See the order of the rules. Put the more specific rules first and the more  general rules last.

Comment: the logout filter seems to work (changed the link to `<a href="/SSP/logout">`) but the login issue still exists. I cannot get a clean `https://localhost:8443/SSP/login.jsp` URL which is able to perform a successful login without having that `JSESSIONID=..` stuff in the addressbar. I updated my question above.

Comment: Regarding the logout url: I suppose your application is called SSP? Try href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout" istead of href="/SSP/logout"

Comment: Just found out that I can edit comments only 5 minutes after creating it. So again: Regarding the logout url: I suppose your application is called SSP? Try `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout"` instead of `href="/SSP/logout"`. The result should be the same but the solution is more generic. About the session id. I am new to java ee too. So again, don't know if I got it right. I think a session is created regardless if you are authenticated or not. So i guess there's no need to worry about that.

Comment: yes SSP is the name of my application. About the Session i find this behaviour doo and even filter like `anon` or `noSessionCreation` wont help. I will try your suggestion about the logout url

Comment: Regarding the other open issues. After logout the `LogoutFilter` will redirect you to `/` by default. See https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.3/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/LogoutFilter.html#getRedirectUrl() Since you have the rule `/** = authc` in your `shiro.ini` you can't access `/` once you are logged out. This is why in return the `authc` filter will redirect you to the login.jsp. It has nothing to do with the missing `logout.redirectUrl = /login.jsp`.

Comment: I just found out how to remove the `JSESSIONID` from the url. Configure this `<session-config>
<tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>` in your web.xml. You can find the explantion here: [link](https://software-security.sans.org/blog/2010/08/11/security-misconfigurations-java-webxml-files) under 6) Using URL Parameters for Session Tracking

Comment: that did not work, I updated the code above with my session management configuration from shiro.ini

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want a user to be able to login and grant access to some restricted url after successful login and so on? Do you use Servlet, JSP, JSF or similar to respond with static pages to the client? If yes I think you actually want a session to be created. In that case you only need to configure the tracking mode as stated above (in your web.xml), in order to remove the JSESSIONID from the URL.

Comment: If you really don't want a session at all you need to configure your shiro filters for urls in the correct order. E.g. `/api/** = noSessionCreation, authcBasic` (See the order of the filters: noSessionCreation comes first!)

Comment: I do want a session to be created for a user but only after he loged in. And the JSESSIONID is still visible in the url even thoug I added `<session-config> <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode> </session-config>` in my web.xml